# How to pass an object to a web component generated width Vue?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component, web-component, vue-directives

My component has to render an object to fill the content. When I am working in the Vue project, I have not problem to pass this object with

```
<my-compnent :card="card"></my-component>
```

But when I tried to use the built component, it doesn't read "MyCard" as an object, ir reads as a string... please, some help

I have tried in the same way that vue, using :card but it doesn´t work, if I only use card="card" it get access to the component but without the object

My code:

```
<script>
 card =
     {
        name: 'card',
        graphic: 'https://static.anychart.com/images/gallery/v8/line-charts-line-chart.png',
        subtitle: 'about this card',
        info: 'this is a test content card',
        selector1: [
          { name: 'opt 1' },
          { name: 'opt 2' },
          { name: 'opt 3' }
        ],
        selector2: [
          { name: 'opt A' },
          { name: 'opt B' },
          { name: 'opt C' }
        ]
      }
</script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>
<body>
   <my-component card="card"></card>
</body>
```

And the error:

*[Vue warn]: Invalid prop: type check failed for prop "card". Expected Object, got String with value "card".*

Also I have tried

```
<my-component :card="card"></card>
```

but this only works in a vue project, not in exported web-components. It gives this error:

*[Vue warn]: Error in render: "TypeError: can't access property "name", _vm.card is undefined"*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`card="card"` will pass the string 'card' as value to the `card` attribute. If you want to pass a JS object tp an exported web component outside Vue, then you'll have to do it in JS itself.

```
<script>
 const card =
     {
        name: 'card',
        graphic: 'https://static.anychart.com/images/gallery/v8/line-charts-line-chart.png',
        subtitle: 'about this card',
        info: 'this is a test content card',
        selector1: [
          { name: 'opt 1' },
          { name: 'opt 2' },
          { name: 'opt 3' }
        ],
        selector2: [
          { name: 'opt A' },
          { name: 'opt B' },
          { name: 'opt C' }
        ]
      }
  let comp = document.querySelector('my-component')
  comp.card = card
</script>
<body>
   <my-component card="card"></card>
</body>
```

You can use `v-bind:card` or simply ':card' only if you're working inside vue project, in which case you don't need to use exported component. But in this case the object `card` needs to be passed to the `data` property of your Vue instance, otherwise Vue can't find it. This is why you get the error.

```
<script>
const app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    card,
  },
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<my-element :user.prop="{ name: 'jack' }"></my-element>

<!-- shorthand equivalent -->
<my-element .user="{ name: 'jack' }"></my-element>
```